# What is the binary (i.e., in bits) representation of the byte ‘E3’?

Tags: emv

During an EMV transaction, all information exchanged between terminal and card is encoded in byte strings. In order to understand the content of the messages and give meaning to the bits, you should first get familiar with the hexadecimal notation. One byte can be represented by two hexadecimal numbers, or eight binary (0,1) numbers.
What is the binary (i.e., in bits) representation of the byte ‘E3’?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because: It is an obvious homework question, and the OP has shown no effort in finding out the answer.

Comment: @SolomonSlow We don't really need a custom close reason for this. Homework questions alone aren't offtopic, and the lack of effort could just fall under either Unclear or Too Broad.

Comment: @Carcigenicate But the question is clear, and very specific. I've often wished for a close reason of "No effort" to match the downvote button.

Comment: @Flimzy I would consider it too broad because they've stated the whole problem clearly, but haven't said what exact part of it they need help with.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: When you look at it that way, I get your point.

Comment: @arbeline have a look e.g. [here](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-binary-converter)..Good luck with your project!

Comment: Thank you all, sorry if i caused any inconvenience it was my first question here. I did research i knew the answer before posting here, i just wanted to confirm with specialist so i knew i was in the right path. But anyways thank you specially you @Carcigenicate and you vlp

Comment: @arbeline You may want to give a read over [ask] if you intend on asking here again in the future. We have quite high quality standards, and rigid guidelines for what is and isn't on topic. In this question's current form, it isn't appropriate for the site, thus our discussion.

Answer (score 0):

The EMV tags follow Packed BCD format. It means a byte can hold two Hexadecimal values. In your case it becomes

```
[ [ 1110 ] [ 0011 ] ]
```

. The first nibble holds the binary representation for E and the second one holds for 3.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use Programmer Calculator given in Windows and Linux as well to convert Hexadecimal values into binary as follows: 
[image]